# How would I assign a variable to destructured data from an API call?

Tags: javascript

If I have,

```
let results = null;

try {
    const {
        hits: { hits: queryAsAWhole }
    } = await client.search({
        q:
            "a AND b AND c AND d AND e AND f AND G AND H"
    });
```

How would I assign `queryAsAWhole` to results in one call without doing,

```
let results = null;

try {
    const {
        hits: { hits: queryAsAWhole }
    } = await client.search({
        q:
            "a AND b AND c AND d AND e AND f AND G AND H"
    });

    results = queryAsAWhole;
```

As a one liner?

Comment: Can you share a basic example of what `client.search()` returns? I'm not so sure that you can really make this a one-liner, as it would seem that the only the right side of the assignment requires a `try...catch`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share as it is confidential, it is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch) module, returns `response.hits.hits`

Comment: I wasn't requesting that you share the data returned, rather just the *shape*. Without knowing what `client.search()` returns, we're blind to the right-side of your destructuring assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're already using `querAsAWhile` as an alias for `hits`, you can either use `results` as an alias :

```
const {
  hits: { hits: results }
} = await client.search({
```

or `results` would have the return value from an IIFE :

```js
let results = (() => {
  try {
    const obj = {
      hits: {
        hits: "hello"
      }
    };

    const {
      hits: { hits: queryAsAWhole }
    } = obj;

    return queryAsAWhole;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
})();

console.log(results);
```